# Preview icon images in Android Studio editor's sidebar

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, editor, development-environment

I know it's not a vital problem, but it occupies my mind. As you can see in the image, Android Studio shows a nice preview of some images in the editor's sidebar.
There are 3 PNG images with the same format and same dimensions. But Android Studio only shows the preview for just two of them.
I'm using **Android Studio 2.0 Beta 2** .

[image]

Does anyone knows the reason behind or is there any special property for the images to be able to be previewed by Android Studio?

I'll appreciate any answer.

Comment: i think because of this its not showing "libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited"

Comment: try to generate Signed APK notice this type of error in Gradle console. this error show at any image. that image not showing